# Query in sql spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have this table

```
HODTTO         HOOE     HOTPAC       
20180620    1045380066   ANCA              
20180620    1045382011   ANCA              
20180620    1045382126   ANCA              
20180620    1045360842   ANDE              
20180620    1045360842   ANDE              
...
```

I'd like to know the relationship between all event of the table agains the quantities of `hotpac=ANDE WHERE DISTINCT HOOE` following this eq.  `order by hdtto`

```
     (count(hooe) - count(hotpac=ANDE where disctinct hooe) 
KPI= -----------------------------------------------------
                         count(hooe)
```

But I don't know how to do it

The table that I really want is something like this:

```
hodtto       count(distinct hooe)       kpi                                                                           
20180601          4                      99                                                                    
20180602          6                      98                                                                              
20180603          8                      96                                                                                           
20180604          4                      97
```

Comment: And what results do you want for the data you have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
select 1 - (count(hooe) * 1.0 / count(distinct case when hotpack = 'ANDE' then hooe end) as kpi
from t;
```

Are you use you don't want `count(distinct hooe)` for the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed functions:

```
SELECT *, 
  1.0*(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY hooe)
    - SUM(CASE WHEN hotpac='ANDE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY hooe))
   /(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY hooe)) AS KPI 
FROM tab
ORDER BY hodtto;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/OMTF93506)**